# CSS - Adding menu icon causes problem with website layout

Tags: html, css

another question regarding my school project. We have to add a menu to our website and i thus googled for a premade menu. Unfortunately, as soon as i add the menu the website layout doesn't really work any more. I already tried making the position absolute but haven't got it to work.

```
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>Virtual Reality - Headsetüberblick</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="colorlib-main-nav" role="navigation">
            <a href="#" class="js-colorlib-nav-toggle colorlib-nav-toggle active"><i></i></a>
            <div class="js-fullheight colorlib-table">
                <div class="img" style="background-image: url(images/bg_3.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="colorlib-table-cell js-fullheight">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <h1 class="mb-4"><a href="index.html" class="logo">Gruppe 1</a></h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Virtual Relity</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html"><span>Thema 2</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog.html"><span>Thema 3</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Thema 4</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <a href="#" class="js-colorlib-nav-toggle colorlib-nav-toggle "><i></i></a>

        <div class="introduction header h-100 container-fluid d-flex w-100 text-center">
                <h1 id="h-100" class="h-100 row col-12 align-items-center text-center display-1 justify-content-center">VIRTUAL REALITY</h1>            
        </div>

        <div class="h-100 container-fluid row">
            <h2 style="margin-top: 50px;" class="center col-12 text-center display-4">Was ist Virtual Reality (VR)</h2>
            <p class="center col-12 lead">Eine virtuelle Welt oder ein Computerspiel, in das der Nutzer mit Hilfe eines VR-Headsets vollständig eintauchen kann</p>
        </div>

...

        <div class="footer-basic">
            <footer>
                <p class="copyright">Lukas Strutz 2021</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

        

      
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            function toggleDiv(whichdiv) {
            var x = document.getElementById(whichdiv);
                if (x.style.display === "none") {
                    x.style.display = "flex";
                } else {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                }
            } 

            (function($) {

            "use strict";

            var fullHeight = function() {

                $('.js-fullheight').css('height', $(window).height());
                $(window).resize(function(){
                    $('.js-fullheight').css('height', $(window).height());
                });

            };
            fullHeight();

            var burgerMenu = function() {

                $('.js-colorlib-nav-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if( $('body').hasClass('menu-show') ) {
                        $('body').removeClass('menu-show');
                        $('#colorlib-main-nav > .js-colorlib-nav-toggle').removeClass('show');
                    } else {
                        $('body').addClass('menu-show');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#colorlib-main-nav > .js-colorlib-nav-toggle').addClass('show');
                        }, 900);
                    }
                })
            };
            burgerMenu();


            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
/*
    Stylesheet zur VR-Website - Lukas Strutz 2021

    Inhalt:
    1. Grundsätztliches Design der Website
    2. Design des Menüs (bezogen von Colorlib)
    3. Design des Footers (bezogen von epicbootstrap.com)

*/


@font-face {
    font-family: 'cf_glitch_cityregular';
    src: url('fonts/cfglitchcityregular-l1vz-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/cfglitchcityregular-l1vz-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

html, body {
    background-color: black;

    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;

}

#h-100{
    /*height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;*/

    /*padding-top: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 30%;*/

    text-align: center;
}
/*h1 {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}*/

h1{
    font-family: "cf_glitch_cityregular";
}

.introduction {
    background-image: url("beat-saber-intro.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.sketchfab-embed-wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

iframe{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

header {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.center{
    text-align: center;
}

.steamvr{
    background-image: url("https://www.vrnerds.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Steam-VR-Spiele.png");
    
}

.oculus{
    background-image: url("oculus.jpg");
}



/* Menu*/
.img {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center; }
  
  #colorlib-main-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.99);
    z-index: 1002;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
    -ms-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
    -o-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
    transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    overflow-y: scroll; }
    #colorlib-main-nav .colorlib-table {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%; }
      #colorlib-main-nav .colorlib-table .img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 1; }
        #colorlib-main-nav .colorlib-table .img:after {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          right: 0;
          content: '';
          background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }
      #colorlib-main-nav .colorlib-table .colorlib-table-cell {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle; }
    #colorlib-main-nav .colorlib-nav-toggle {
      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;
      right: 40px;
      padding: 20px;
      height: 44px;
      width: 44px;
      line-height: 0;
      padding: 0 !important;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
      -o-transition: 0.3s;
      transition: 0.3s; }
      @media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
        #colorlib-main-nav .colorlib-nav-toggle {
          -webkit-transition: none;
          -o-transition: none;
          transition: none; } }
      #colorlib-main-nav .colorlib-nav-toggle i {
        top: 18px !important;
        left: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        line-height: 0;
        text-indent: 0; }
      #colorlib-main-nav .colorlib-nav-toggle.show {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1; }
      #colorlib-main-nav .colorlib-nav-toggle:hover i::before, #colorlib-main-nav .colorlib-nav-toggle:hover i::after {
        content: '';
        width: 40px;
        height: 2px;
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0; }
    .menu-show #colorlib-main-nav {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -moz-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
      -o-transform: scale(1);
      transform: scale(1); }
    #colorlib-main-nav .logo {
      font-size: 40px;
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      font-weight: 700;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      line-height: 1.5;
      font-family: "Poppins", Arial, sans-serif; }
      #colorlib-main-nav .logo span {
        font-size: 14px;
        display: block;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
        letter-spacing: 8px; }
    #colorlib-main-nav ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      display: block; }
      @media (max-width: 767.98px) {
        #colorlib-main-nav ul {
          padding: 20px 0 0 0; } }
      #colorlib-main-nav ul li {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        text-transform: uppercase; }
        #colorlib-main-nav ul li a {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          padding: 5px 0; }
          #colorlib-main-nav ul li a span {
            color: white;
            position: relative;
            padding: 0 10px; }
            #colorlib-main-nav ul li a span small {
              position: absolute;
              bottom: 7px;
              left: -30px;
              font-size: 16px;
              color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
              border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); }
          #colorlib-main-nav ul li a:hover, #colorlib-main-nav ul li a:active, #colorlib-main-nav ul li a:focus {
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none; }
            #colorlib-main-nav ul li a:hover span:before, #colorlib-main-nav ul li a:active span:before, #colorlib-main-nav ul li a:focus span:before {
              visibility: visible;
              -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
              -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
              -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
              -o-transform: scaleX(1);
              transform: scaleX(1); }
        #colorlib-main-nav ul li.active a span {
          color: #f8b500; }
          #colorlib-main-nav ul li.active a span:before {
            background: #fec771;
            visibility: visible;
            -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
            -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
            -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
            -o-transform: scaleX(1);
            transform: scaleX(1); }
  
  header {
    padding: 2em 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    margin: 0 auto; }
    @media (max-width: 767.98px) {
      header {
        padding: 1em 0;
        position: absolute; } }
    header .colorlib-navbar-brand {
      float: left; }
      header .colorlib-navbar-brand .colorlib-logo {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #fff;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        font-weight: 600;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        line-height: 1.5;
        font-family: "Poppins", Arial, sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase; }
        header .colorlib-navbar-brand .colorlib-logo span {
          font-size: 11px;
          display: block;
          font-weight: 300;
          color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
          letter-spacing: 7px; }
        header .colorlib-navbar-brand .colorlib-logo i {
          color: #fec771;
          position: absolute;
          top: -18px;
          bottom: 0;
          left: 7px;
          font-size: 48px; }
        header .colorlib-navbar-brand .colorlib-logo:hover {
          text-decoration: none !important; }
        header .colorlib-navbar-brand .colorlib-logo:active, header .colorlib-navbar-brand .colorlib-logo:focus {
          outline: none;
          text-decoration: none; }
  
  .colorlib-nav-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none; }
    .colorlib-nav-toggle.active i::before, .colorlib-nav-toggle.active i::after {
      background: #000; }
    .colorlib-nav-toggle.dark.active i::before, .colorlib-nav-toggle.dark.active i::after {
      background: #000; }
    .colorlib-nav-toggle:hover, .colorlib-nav-toggle:focus, .colorlib-nav-toggle:active {
      outline: none;
      border-bottom: none !important; }
    .colorlib-nav-toggle i {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 2px;
      color: white;
      font: bold 14px/.4 Helvetica;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-indent: -55px;
      background: #fff;
      -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
      -o-transition: all .2s ease-out;
      transition: all .2s ease-out; }
      .menu-show .colorlib-nav-toggle i {
        background: #fff;
        color: #fff; }
      .colorlib-nav-toggle i::before, .colorlib-nav-toggle i::after {
        content: '';
        width: 30px;
        height: 2px;
        background: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
        -o-transition: 0.2s;
        transition: 0.2s; }
        .menu-show .colorlib-nav-toggle i::before, .menu-show .colorlib-nav-toggle i::after {
          background: #fff; }
        @media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
          .colorlib-nav-toggle i::before, .colorlib-nav-toggle i::after {
            -webkit-transition: none;
            -o-transition: none;
            transition: none; } }
    .colorlib-nav-toggle.dark i {
      position: relative;
      color: #fff;
      background: #fff;
      -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
      -o-transition: all .2s ease-out;
      transition: all .2s ease-out; }
      .colorlib-nav-toggle.dark i::before, .colorlib-nav-toggle.dark i::after {
        background: #fff;
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
        -o-transition: 0.2s;
        transition: 0.2s; }
        @media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
          .colorlib-nav-toggle.dark i::before, .colorlib-nav-toggle.dark i::after {
            -webkit-transition: none;
            -o-transition: none;
            transition: none; } }
  
  .colorlib-nav-toggle i::before {
    top: -7px; }
  
  .colorlib-nav-toggle i::after {
    bottom: -7px; }
  
  .colorlib-nav-toggle:hover i::before {
    top: -10px; }
  
  .colorlib-nav-toggle:hover i::after {
    bottom: -10px; }
  
  .colorlib-nav-toggle.active i {
    background: transparent; }
  
  .colorlib-nav-toggle.active i::before {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    transform: rotateZ(45deg); }
  
  .colorlib-nav-toggle.active i::after {
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-45deg); }
  
  .colorlib-nav-toggle {
    float: right;
    z-index: 1003;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 0; }
    @media (max-width: 767.98px) {
      .colorlib-nav-toggle {
        right: 10px; } }
  
  .hero-wrap {
    background: #202020; }
    .hero-wrap .slider-text .desc h1 {
      font-size: 6vw;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase; }
    .hero-wrap .slider-text .desc h3 {
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      font-size: 18px; }


.footer-basic {
    padding:40px 0;
    background-color:#000;
    /*color:#6b6c6d;*/
}


.footer-basic .copyright {
    margin-top:15px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:13px;
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin-bottom:0;
}

/* Credit to https://epicbootstrap.com/snippets/footer-basic */
```

You can also see this online at: https://lukasstrutz.de/website/thisdoesnotwork.html

Comment: Can you please specify your problem.

Comment: The problem is, that the logo is added on the right top and after adding it i get a horizontal scrollbar, which leads to bad user experience

Comment: Add right: 20px; in .colorlib-nav-toggle.